# How to take user input in Shiny and pass it onto a function? reactive is not working

Tags: r, shiny

Issue description:
Attempting to create a shiny app that takes user input (real number) to generate a histogram of transformed data.

The following recreates the issue (edited to reproduce the error)

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

# flow cytometry specific packages

flowlibs <- c("CytoExploreR","flowWorkspace","flowWorkspaceData")
sapply(flowlibs, FUN = function(x){
  if(!(x %in% installed.packages())) BiocManager::install(x,update = F)
  library(x,character.only = T)
})

datafolder <- system.file("extdata",package = "flowWorkspaceData")

# create cytoset
set1 <- load_cytoset_from_fcs(path = datafolder,pattern = "a2004")

# list of available markers
markers <- markernames(set1)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    
    # select samples
    selectInput(inputId = "sampleID", label = "Sample", choices = sampleNames(set1), multiple = F),
    
    # select marker
    selectInput(inputId = "markerID",label = "Marker",choices = markers,multiple = F),
    
    # extra parameters for transformations
    sliderInput(inputId = "parameter",label = "Additional parameter",min = log(1/1E4),max = log(1E4),value = 4.5,width = 100),
  ),
  plotOutput(outputId = "histogram")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  param <- reactive({
    input$parameter
  })
  output$histogram <- renderPlot({
    
    print(param()) # prints to console the correct value from sliderInput
    
    cyto_transformer_arcsinh(
      x = set1[[input$sampleID]],
      channels = input$markerID,
      M = param()
    ) # leads to error.   
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Upon inspection of the function cyto_transformer_arcsinh, the following seems to be what is causing issue:

```
args <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE))[-1]
```

The output of which seems to be:

```
$x
set1[[input$sampleID]]

$channels
input$markerID

$M
param()
```

When running it as is the following message is displayed:

```
Error in h: error in evaluating the argument 'expr' in selecting a method for function 'eval': could not find function "param"
```

When running it my manually supplying the value for **M**, the plot is generation without an issue.

Question:

How do I supply the value collected by sliderInput to **M** ?

Not really sure what to try at this point. I want to simply visualize how changing transformation parameters affects the data.

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: can you set `m=param()`; and then in the call use `M = m`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I get the same error message: error in evaluating the argument 'expr' in selecting a method for function 'eval': object 'm' not found.

Comment: Try adding `req(param())` above the line `print(param())`

Comment: Please post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want someone to help you.  For example, object `set1` is not defined.

Comment: - added `req(param())`; lead to same error.
- have made an attempt to provide full script that should reproduce the error.